# Query a JSON data file with SQL or any other means to filter out specific data based in key from a large json data set

Tags: json

Any suggestion on how to narrow down on to a key in big JSON data file with SQL or any other means.

I have tried looping and inserting the data in a table format and then querying, but that is time consuming when json data format keeps changing. therefore, I was wondering if there is an easier alternative

Sample data:

```
{
  "PanelCode" : "A",
  "PanelHead" : "Menu 1 ",
  "Items" : 
  [
   { "code" : "A1" , "name" : "ABC"   , "active" : "1" , "img" : "1.png"    , "url" : "something.xxx?something1()" }, 
   { "code" : "A2" , "name" : "CED"   , "active" : "1" , "img" : "2.png"    , "url" : "something.xxx?something2()" }, 
   { "code" : "A3" , "name" : "OLE"   , "active" : "1" , "img" : "2.png"    , "url" : "something.xxx?something3()" }, 
   { "code" : "A4" , "name" : "XER"   , "active" : "1" , "img" : "4.png"    , "url" : "something.xxx?something4()" }, 
   { "code" : "A5" , "name" : "MEL"   , "active" : "1" , "img" : "5.png"    , "url" : "something.xxx?something5()" } 
  ] 
 } 
 , 
 { 
  "PanelCode" : "B", 
  "PanelHead" : "Menu 2", 
  "Items" : 
  [ 
   { "code" : "B1" , "name" : "RBC"  , "active" : "1" , "img" : "6.png"    , "url" : "something.xxx?something6()" }, 
   { "code" : "B2" , "name" : "SRH"  , "active" : "1" , "img" : "7.png"    , "url" : "something.xxx?something7()" }, 
   { "code" : "B3" , "name" : "KKR"  , "active" : "1" , "img" : "8.png"    , "url" : "something.xxx?something8()" }
  ] 
 } 
 ,  
 { 
  "PanelCode" : "Z", 
  "PanelHead" : "Menu X", 
  "Items" : 
  [ 
   { "code" : "Z1" , "name" : "SW" , "active" : "1" , "img" : "91.png" , "url" : "something.xxx?something91()" },  
   { "code" : "Z2" , "name" : "HW" , "active" : "1" , "img" : "92.png" , "url" : "something.xxx?something92()" },  
   { "code" : "Z3" , "name" : "MW" , "active" : "1" , "img" : "93.png" , "url" : "something.xxx?something93()" }  
  ]
 }
```

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: A-Z panels, each panels having between 1-100 items. Overall, json file lines can range from a few hundreds to thousands. In the sample data, A - Z panel. 26 Panels each having random number of items

Comment: So you have about ~2,6k items tops. Even if you double this number, it's not a big size. You could easily store these in a database that supports json indexing. Look into [PostgreSQL jsonb indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html) or [mongodb Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/). You can have multiple indexes on the same collections to cover all your usecases.

Comment: thanks. i'll explore that option.